# Как выбрать правильный способ определения QList

Tags: qt, c++

Здравствуйте, при попытках написать на C++ надоевшую всем донельзя "жизнь" Конвея, столкнулся с неожиданной для себя проблемой.
 К сожалению, пока не могу показать собственно сам код программы, но попробую примерно объяснить. 
Не буду рассказывать принцип игры, его все знают. Для реализации всей этой красоты я создал класс, содержащий координаты клетки и значение описывающее закрашена ли она. Затем был создан список из энного количества таких классов.
 Проблема в том, что мне нужно использовать данные из этого списка в двух методах, причем так, чтобы изменения списка в первом методе влияли на второй. Так вышло из-за необходимости использовать paintevent для собственно рисования и mousepressevent для задачи начальных позиций закрашенных клеток, и собственно последующих расчетов. Я пробовал объявлять список как переменную внутри класса, объявлял ее в исходнике как глобальную, но изменения в одном методе после его окончания просто стирались и в следующем методе список был уже чист. уже и не знаю как определять его. Причем программа выдает разные ошибки, то QList "index out of range", то просто намертво зависает.
 Задачка и вопрос довольно простые, но я еще школьник, и столкнулся с qt lf b c++ не так давно.

Comment: Если вам нужно иметь две версии списка, то заведите _в явном виде_ два списка. Если нужна одна версия списка, заводите только одну. Этот список (или эти списки) раздавайте нужным классам (например, по ссылке), пусть они пользуются.

Comment: Нужен один. Один-единственный, но прикол в том, что как я его не объявляю, а в одном методе происходят изменения, а в другом их программа уже не видит и выдает ошибку QList "index out of range",

Answer (score 1):

Список можно объявить как обычно.
В функцию, которая НЕ должна его изменять - передавать по ссылке или указателю.
В функцию, которая ДОЛЖНА его изменять - передавать по константной ссылке или указателю.

Если это не поможет, то в QtCreator'е есть отладчик, с его помощью можно отследить работу программы и узнать, где находится ошибка.

Comment: Наоборот - которая не должна - по константной ссылке.